# Can't tap buttons on the left side of 4" iPhone

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

This is absolutely confusing. On a 3.5" iPhone simulator, all of the UIButtons on my app work just fine. However, when I launch on the 4" iPhone simulator, all of the UIButtons on the left side of the app do not receive any click events.

Below are screenshots of the 3.5" size and the 4" size. On the 4" size, I've added a line. Left of that line, none of the buttons receive click events. To the right of that line, all buttons behave normally. The left side of buttons 2, 5, and 8 do not respond to clicks, but the right sides of those buttons do respond.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE----
Thanks to @iccir, I've discovered more info. Apparently, my UIWindow is only 320x480 instead of 568x320 as it should be. I'm not touching the UIWindow in my code except to make it key and visible. In my MainWindow.xib I connect its IBOutlet to my rootViewController.

```
<UIWindow: 0xc097d50; frame = (0 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xc098460>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0xc097e70>>
```

I'm flabberghasted. Any idea why the UIWindow is incorrectly sized?

Comment: I think this is issue with the frame sizes. So try to check the view sizes(To which view you are adding the buttons check that view frames)

Comment: try on device,before trying anything else..

Comment: I don't have an iPhone 5 for device testing.

Comment: If you post some of the code that adds the buttons, it might be easier to help out – or some information on the xib, if you're using that.

Comment: @matsr all of the buttons are part of the xib, I'm not adding any programmatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue:  Your UIButton is outside of the bounds of one of its superviews.  If `clipsToBounds`/`masksToBounds` is set to NO (the default), your UIButton is still going to show up, but touch events aren't going to be sent to it.

Let's simplify this case.  Suppose a view controller with the following code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIColor *fadedRedColor  = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.25];
    UIColor *fadedBlueColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:0.25];

    CGRect containerFrame = CGRectMake(25,  25,  100, 100);
    CGRect buttonFrame    = CGRectMake(100, 100, 64,  44);

    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerFrame];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setFrame:buttonFrame];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(_handleButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [container setBackgroundColor:fadedRedColor];
    [button    setBackgroundColor:fadedBlueColor];

    [container addSubview:button];

    [[self view] addSubview:container];
}

- (void) _handleButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Moooooo!");
}
```

Which looks like this:
[image: Screenshot 1]

The button is contained in `container`, but it resides outside of the container's bounds (the container is 100 pixels wide and 100 pixels tall, the button's origin is at `100, 100`).

When you touch the screen, UIKit is going to start at the top of the view hierarchy (UIWindow) and call `-[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]` recursively until it finds the view that should handle the touch.  However, in this example, UIKit will never descend into the container (since you touched outside its boundary), and thus the button subview will not be hit.

If we instead change the `buttonFrame` to be `50, 50`, it looks like this:
[image: Screenshot 2]

The part of the button that overlaps with the container will respond to touch event.  The part that resides outside of the container will not:

[image: Screenshot 3]

To debug a view that isn't fully touchable, you can try a debugging function like the following:

```
static void sDebugViewThatIsntTouchable(UIView *view)
{
    UIView *superview = [view superview];

    while (superview) {
        CGRect rectInSuperview = [view convertRect:[view bounds] toView:superview];

        CGPoint topLeft     = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rectInSuperview), CGRectGetMinY(rectInSuperview));
        CGPoint topRight    = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rectInSuperview), CGRectGetMinY(rectInSuperview));
        CGPoint bottomLeft  = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rectInSuperview), CGRectGetMaxY(rectInSuperview));
        CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rectInSuperview), CGRectGetMaxY(rectInSuperview));

        if (![superview pointInside:topLeft withEvent:nil]) {
            NSLog(@"Top left point of view %@ not inside superview %@", view, superview);
        }

        if (![superview pointInside:topRight withEvent:nil]) {
            NSLog(@"Top right point of view %@ not inside superview %@", view, superview);
        }

        if (![superview pointInside:bottomLeft withEvent:nil]) {
            NSLog(@"Bottom left point of view %@ not inside superview %@", view, superview);
        }

        if (![superview pointInside:bottomRight withEvent:nil]) {
            NSLog(@"Bottom right point of view %@ not inside superview %@", view, superview);
        }

        superview = [superview superview];
    }
};
```

---

Edit:
As you mentioned in the comments, the culprit view was the main UIWindow, which was sized to 320x480 rather than 320x568.  **Turning on "Full Screen at Launch" in the xib fixed this**.

Of course, the question is: "Why?" :)

If you pull up your xib file in a text editor, you will notice that a width of 320 and height of 480 are hardcoded to the window.  When the xib is decoded at launch time, the window is initially constructed with this 320x480 frame.

UIKit then queries `-[UIWindow resizesToFullScreen]` (a private method).  If this returns YES, the UIWindow does the equivalent of `[self setFrame:[[self window] bounds]]`.

Toggling the "Full Screen at Launch" flag in Interface Builder directly toggles the private `UIWindow.resizesToFullScreen` flag.

Comment: This function was perfect, thanks! It turns out that my `self.view` is the correct size, but the UIWindow is 320x480! So.. what the hell is up with that? I'll keep looking.

Comment: Are you creating the UIWindow manually in code or in a xib/storyboard?    If manually, are will want to use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` or `-applicationFrame` for the window's frame rather than a hardcoded value.

Comment: I'm using an old MainWindow.xib which was generated by Xcode.

Comment: Considering the MainWindow.xib was generated by Xcode probably 3 years ago, I decided to review all of the settings for it in Xcode. I noticed the "Full Screen at Launch" was not checked and found these docs suggesting it should always be checked: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html

I checked it, reran and all of those buttons are working now! Please include this little bit about the MainWindow.xib in your answer and I'll award you the bounty! Thanks!

Comment: Added!  I don't normally use xibs, so I had to do a bit of spelunking to figure out exactly what that checkbox was controlling. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, this happens only in the landscape mode, right ?
I had the same issue in my app when I was developing specifically for the iPhone-4S. But when I began testing on the iPhone-5, touches on the bottom did not work. It were the `frame`. Make sure `frames` are set to `bounds`, both in the code, and the `XIB` file (if there is one). Different `frames`/`bounds` in the `man` and `xib` files, might also result in such behaviour.

I eventually removed the `xib` files, and did everything programmatically. One thing I learnt was, set your frames in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods instead of `viewDidLoad`. Also check the `frame`/`bounds` in your `RootViewController`. One last thing, try not to use constant value for `frames`, use referential frames with respect to superview.

PS, one way to know if it really is the frames/bounds that are responsible for this behaviour is, setting the `masksToBounds` to `YES`, for the `views`. That way, your views will not be visible outside their rects.

Comment: I don't set my frames programmatically at all, they are automatically set when the xibs are loaded. I've verified that the view is 568x320. The Cards (UIButtons) are added directly to the main View and are not outside of the super view. For example, one of the cards I can't tap is at (18, 60) 50x64.

Comment: @iccir answer is right.
This was going to be my second advice. In your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method in the `AppDelegate` file, you should set the `applicationFrame` accordingly. One good choice would be using the `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` but you might want to check it's behaviour on iOS7. I haven't yet migrated to XCode5/iOS7 so cannot say for sure.